# When mutex lock isn't enough?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I know multithreaded programming is supposed to be hard. But it seems things find a weird way of breaking. For instance, I have multiple threads both changing the colors of and writing to the console (its an error log).

There were 2 problems:

- jambled text
- color changes interfering/not at the right times

When I added a mutex lock to the section that changes console color and writes to the console, it helped with the jambled text (haven't seen any since the mutex lock) but the console color is still wrong.

So it appears a mutex is not enough!  I am now thinking I will need a queue, and a single thread that waits on that queue and flushes it out when there's stuff in it. So my question is, how do you gauge when a mutex lock is enough?  As soon as pipes/files/comm w/ another process is involved?

Comment: It's really hard to say anything from your description of the problem. Locks are usually enough, because they isolate transactions that do atomic modifications.

Comment: It reads as you have two mutexes or incorrectly combing the colour change and write into one locked operation.

Comment: It sounds like your functions alter a global state (console color) and then assume that global state remains valid even after they release the mutex.

Comment: can you isolate the relevant code that changes the colors and create a simpler program that shows the bug?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by *not enough*. More mutexes? Larger scoped locking? Something else? This question is quite vague.

Comment: By "not enough" I mean having to create a queue (of log messages) that gets flushed out by only one thread.  The queue is made threadsafe, and we have good control with mutex over memory writes

Comment: A mutex will be enough if you use it properly.  Andrei's suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Yes, the problem doesn't isn't the mutex, it is your implementation.

Comment: It definitely sounds like you're using the mutex incorrectly; your "atomic" operation (what's surrounded by the mutex) should contain both the colour change and the writing of the text, or there's no guarantees on how those will be synchronized.

It would be nice if you posted some code and a clear example of what you expect to see & what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

A mutex (such as boost/pthread mutex) will guarantee exclusive access to a shared resource between different threads (but not processes, you need a named semaphore for that).

It sounds like your shared resource is access to the terminal. Just because you lock it when you change the color, doesn't mean it will be locked when you decide to change the color. Both threads would lock the mutex before either writing to the terminal or changing color. Making two mutexes isn't overly necessary since you're still protecting a single shared resource (the terminal).

If a thread wants to both write text and change the color, the mutex must support recursive locking, such as [recursive_mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.recursive_mutex).